# Is it possible for HTTPS server to provide different SSL certificate based on HTTP headers?

Tags: ssl, https

I am trying to connect to a service over HTTPS, and currently the connection fails due to certificate mismatch with the hostname. I am receiving different certificate host name depending on whether I connect using hostname or IP address. The hostname does resolve to exact same IP address, but it consistently keeps giving different certificate for the IP address when using curl. Using python requests module, it always gives me the certificate I get with curl and IP address (which is unfortunately the wrong one).

Any explanations what might be going on here?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication

Comment: and https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/community/faq/#what-are-hostname-doesn-t-match-errors